# Setting object name dynamically Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object which contains another object with key values like this

```js
let Obj1:any = {    
  ColumnID: {
    ColumnName:[markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()] ,
    Value: [markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDisplayVal()]
  }
}
```

What i want to do is set a value to columnid as well like this:

```html
Obj1{
  ColumnID: ID1(I need to get dynamically){
    ColumnName: Test
    Value: 1
  }
}
```

meaning that ColumnID should stay static but its value should change.

so far i have tried doing it like this

```js
let Obj1:any = {    
  ColumnID:[markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnID()] {
    ColumnName:[markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()] ,
    Value: [markerObj.infoIdentities[1].getDisplayVal()]
  }
}
```

But the syntax is wrong

Any way I can do it?

Comment: What is the meaning of `ColumnID` being both `ID1` and a sub-object?  I don't think such a thing is possible in JavaScript.  Can you give a concrete example of the JavaScript object you want?

Comment: i mean to say that the columnid which i am giving should be dynamical for ex like this   `let infoValues = markerObj.infoIdentities[1];
       let cid: infoValues.getColumnInfo().getColumnID(); 
       let Obj1:any = { 
        
             cid: {
              columnName:[infoValues.getDataColumnIdentity()[0].getColumnInfo().getColumnName()] ,
              columnValue: [infoValues.getDisplayVal()]
            }
          }`  im trying to get the cids name according to whats its value is stored in DB